# Unable to build android from titanium appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-android

When i'm trying to build my app for android, i received following error from console :

```
[INFO] :   No aidl files to compile, continuing
[INFO] :   Generating i18n files
[INFO] :   Generating    /Users/xxx/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/jobmobile/build/android/res/values/theme.xml
[INFO] :   Packaging application: /Users/xxx/Library/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "/Users/xxx/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/jobmobile/build/android/gen" "-M" "/Users/xxx/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/jobmobile/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "/Users/xxx/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/jobmobile/build/android/bin/assets" "-S" "/Users/xxx/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/jobmobile/build/android/res" "-I" "/Users/xxx/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23/android.jar" "-F" "/Users/xxx/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/jobmobile/build/android/bin/app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:com.facebook" "-S" "/var/folders/13/d0dckfds7071zrrts33x0fgm0000gn/T/117118-27860-1lfl9l7/res" "-S" "/var/folders/13/d0dckfds7071zrrts33x0fgm0000gn/T/117118-27860-sgvk1n/res" "-S" "/var/folders/13/d0dckfds7071zrrts33x0fgm0000gn/T/117118-27860-tpzi5i/res"
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/xxx/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/jobmobile/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/job-interim-jobinterim-tempwork-temporary-working-service-qarma-carma-app-jobapp-apple-google-mobile.png: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.
```

So i cannot build my app to android, ios is working well.

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages says "invalid file name". So perhaps you should rename your file to a shorter name?

Comment: Hello,
Thank you, this image is inside build folder so each time i build this folder is not deleted? and i don't have this image either inside :
[ERROR] :  xxx/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/job-interim-jobinterim-tempwork-temporary-working-service-qarma-carma-app-jobapp-apple-google-mobile.png: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.

Comment: With `ti clean` all the folders are cleaned. The image should be located in your `/assets/images` folder or just search for it :)

Comment: Yes, thank you i did ti clean, found the image inside /assets/images folder, deleted it but when buiding titanium recreate it :(

Comment: Hello, i deleted the image, it's true this is the source of the issue, now i face another problem : java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted

Comment: You need to show the full error log in order to help. Are you using any modules in your project? Which SDK version? Sometime you have this error when two modules use Playservices or so